# How to use the new GitHub Projects feature

Tags: github

I don't know when it was available, but now GitHub has a new Projects feature, ref: https://help.github.com/articles/about-projects/

On the Projects creation page it says:

> Drag, drop, and organize your work
>
> Drag and drop cards on kanban-style boards to organize your work and plan projects with teammates.

So I created one, however that "*Drag and drop cards on kanban-style boards*" doesn't work for me, at least not for my chromium-browser under Ubuntu:

```
$ apt-cache policy chromium-browser
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263
  Candidate: 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263
  Version table:
 *** 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
```

Drag and drop cards simply just doesn't work, so there is no errors in the console. Anybody knows how to move those Notes around please?

Update:

So it works for firefox under Ubuntu, but not my latest chromium-browser. 
Can someone confirms whether chromium-browser works under Linux/Ubuntu (or Windows) please?

Comment: Weird. Screenshot? Any errors in the console? Try a hard refresh?

Comment: @Ryan, are you using chromium-browser under Ubuntu? Which browsers have you tried and confirmed working for you?

Comment: No, and none. Screenshot? Any errors in the console? Try a hard refresh?

Comment: I've tried dozen of time of what you're suggesting. Drag and drop cards simply just doesn't work, so there is no errors in the console. I'm asking for a reason, so please at least try it out yourself before question others' judgement.

Comment: The first two are not things to try; they are information that could be added to your question. Here’s another: have you tried a different browser? What was the result?

Comment: OK, gotya. firefox under Ubuntu works. Yet, I still need to know whether chromium-browser under Ubuntu (or Windows) work for someone else or not, which is the gist of my question.

Comment: Hmm. That it works in Firefox rules out a few things that could be going wrong, making this even stranger… it works on Chrome 56, which shouldn’t really be any different from Chromium 55. Do you get the drag cursor when hovering over the cards?

Comment: Yeah, I got that drag cursor when hovering over the cards, and when moving to the other columns, the cursor changes to a fist. But that's it, I don't see the fainted card showing up in the destination column. BTW, dragging cards up & down doesn't work for my latest chromium-browser either. Thanks @Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

**Turns out to be my own problem** -- Tried chromium-browser on another machine, and it worked fine.

`$ apt-cache policy chromium-browser
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263
  Candidate: 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263
  Version table:
 *** 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`